# Can only radon-222 decay into polonium-218?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

Is radon-222 the only element that can decay into polonium-218?

Answer (score 4):

No, [Bismuth-218 forms Polonium-218 by beta decay](http://www.periodictable.com/Isotopes/083.218/index.p.full.dm.html).

Assuming there aren't any nuclei big enough to fission into Bismuth-218, the only ways of forming Bismuth-218 are alpha decay, beta decay and beta plus decay. Beta plus decay would have to be Astatine-218 decaying to Polonium, but this decay mode doesn't happen (actually Polonium-218 beta decays to Astatine). So Radon-222 and Bismuth-218 are the only possible parent nuclei.